# how to align data in CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv

I'm using following code to write data into csv file:

```
filename = "DETAILS.csv"
f = open(filename, "a")
f.write(
    school_name + "," + affiliation_no + "," + state + "," + district + ","   
    + postal_address + "," + phone_no + "," + email_id + "," + web_site + "," 
    + year_of_foundation + "," + date_of_opening + "," + name_of_principal + ","
    + status_of_school + "," + type_of_affiliation + "," + affiliation_period_from + ","
    + affiliation_period_to + "," + name_of_trust_society_managing_committee + "\n")

f.close()
```

I'm getting the output in this format:

[image]

The columns and data are not aligned in csv file.I need one row per each entry. Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: make sure u strip all the variables before writing to csv.

Comment: You have space symbols and `\n` in the fields. Remove it.

Comment: Can you paste the first few rows from the file ``DETAILS.csv`` so that we can see what's actually in your data? This will help understand your problem.

Comment: Schmuddin i have provided few rows of the csv file in the image like.Please, find the image there.

Comment: I guess it's because there's `,` or `\n` in your data?

Comment: @ShashankKumar: The image isn't useful because it shows what the program that you used tried to get out of the CSV file. And obviously, it failed. If you paste the real content of the CSV file, we can see why it failed. We can't see that from the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, when you work with CSV files, you shouldn't use the standard file operations, but use the `writer` and `reader` classes from the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. These classes  take care of quotation marks and of the character used to separate the columns in your file (the comma `,` in your case). They also automatically handle numbers and strings correctly.

So, your code becomes this:

```py
import csv

filename = "DETAILS.csv"
f = open(filename, "a")

# create a CSV writer object:
csvwriter = csv.writer(f)

# create a list of values that will be written to the file:
dat = [school_name, affiliation_no, state, district, postal_address,
       phone_no, email_id, web_site, year_of_foundation, date_of_opening,
       name_of_principal, status_of_school, type_of_affiliation,
       affiliation_period_from, affiliation_period_to, 
       name_of_trust_society_managing_committee]

# write the list to the file, using ',' automatically to separate the 
# columns:
csvwriter.writerow(dat)

f.close()
```

But this alone may not be enough to solve your issue. It looks as if the program that you use to open the CSV file encounters one or more characters that it can't interpret correctly. As pointed out by others, the offending characters may be the tabulator character `\t` or the linebreak character `\n`, but as you seem to refuse to paste some of the actual content of your file, there is no way of knowing that for sure.

However, you can use the following code to replace these characters by a space. The list comprehension handles both numbers and strings:

```py
dat = [val.replace("\n", " ")
          .replace("\t", " ") if type(val) is str else val for val in dat]
```

You can add this before the call to `csvwriter.writerow(dat)` in my code example to make sure that the problematic characters are removed before the row is written to the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you string is not a valid `csv` format.

You should make sure these things:

- Remove the useless comma,if there is comma in your data,you should try to use double quotes, for example:

  `data,"{'response':1}"`
- Remove the `\n`,`\t` character,they will mess up your data.

Have a look at [Comma separated values from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Hope this helps.